# Whats the ruby way to extract an array of values from an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
starting_array = [{key1: 'someKey1Value', key2: 'someKey2Value'}, {key1: 'anotherKey1Value', key2: 'anotherKey2Value'}]
```

I want to end up with this:

```
desired_array = ['someKey2Value', 'anotherKey2Value']
```

Whats the best way to extract all the values for key2 into a separate array?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map) :-

```
starting_array.map { |hash| hash[:key2] }
```

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when I'l allowed to.